# What level student should be able to solve this math question?

Tags: polynomials

I was having a converation about math education in the USA. Would an excellent middle school student, high school student, college freshman, be able to answer this simple question:

[image]

Comment: Possibly better suited to https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks. I have done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple problem of multiplying two quadratics in z and expanding, to find the coefficients. Should be able to done by a high school student, as long as they understand what the notation means.

Comment: would they normally be expected to understand that notation? (It's been a while since I've done high school math)

Comment: They don't usually learn the sum notation. It would be easier to just tell them to multiply 2 quadratics. Maybe write it like this? (ax^2+bx+c)(dx^2+ex+f) and then ask you to find the coefficients of the expanded polynomial